# How to use if else nested

Tags: php, if-statement

Below is the original code

```
else if ($sensor['result_type'] == 'logic')
{
    if($param_value == 1)
    {
        $result['value'] = $param_value;
        $result['value_full'] = $sensor['text_1'];
    }
    else
    {
        $result['value'] = $param_value;
        $result['value_full'] = $sensor['text_0'];
    }
}

else if ($sensor['result_type'] == 'value')
{
```

I would like to increase the results to 6 text results

so depending on the sensor output it will choose the correct result 
is sensor result value =0 full result = text_0
and so on till _text_6

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the `$param_value` in the key name you use in `$sensor`:

```
$result['value'] = $param_value;
$result['value_full'] = $sensor["text_$param_value"];
```

... so without `if ($param_value === 1) ... else if ($param_value === 2) ....`

Comment: Good decoding of a poorly written question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch here, like this

```
switch ($param_value) {
    case 1:
        $result['value'] = $param_value;
        $result['value_full'] = $sensor['text_1'];
        break;
    case 2:
        $result['value'] = $param_value;
        $result['value_full'] = $sensor['text_2'];
        break;
}
```

I am not sure if this is what you're looking for, but wasn't really sure by your question.

You could also do the following

```
 $result['value'] = $param_value;
 $result['value_full'] = $sensor['text_' + (string)$param_value];
```